# How to download OpenGL versions later than 2.1 on MacBook Pro Sierra?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, error, wine

I am trying to run a game called Space Engine using WineSkin on Sierra.  However, the game gives an error saying that the OpenGL version is 2.1, which is below the requirements to run the game.  The minimum to run the game is 3.3.  How can I download OpenGL 3.3 onto my MacBook Pro?

Comment: I would recommend using [wine](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/macosx/download.html) directly instead of through WineSkin as this updated more often.(this may also fix your problem)

Answer (score 1):

The Mac's native OpenGL version will depend on its age; but Apple stopped supporting native OpenGL years ago & many games can only use legacy OGL, which is 2.1.
Unless the game developers themselves support Apple's native OGL, then 2.1 is all you can have, Running a Windows game through an interpreter is unlikely to be able to do that.

Comment: What if I partitioned and used bootcamp?

Comment: possibly. I can't test. Was trying Parallels, but Windows wanted to do so many updates I just gave up... & Boot Camp means I'm stuck in Windows until it's finished, so not going there  :/